# Slow Databinding setup time in C# .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, data-binding

I have got a problem. I have windows forms application with dynamic generated layout, but i have a problem in performance. In this form i use `DataBinding` from `.NET 4.0` and databinding after setup works fine, but he binding setup time for **ONE** control blocking my application on approx **0.7 second.** I have some controls and time of binging setuping is around **2 minutes**.

I trying all possible solutions, I dont have any ideas without write self binding class.
Why is wrong with my code?

```
case "Boolean":
{
    Binding b = new Binding("Checked", __bindingsource, __ep.Name);
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

    /*
     * HERE is the start of problem
     */

    cb.DataBindings.Add(b);

    /*
     * HERE is the end of problem
     */

    __flp.Controls.Add(cb);
    __bindingcontrol.AddBinding(b);
    break;
}
```

Without problem code lines all works fast and without binding ;-( but i want binding turn on in normal speed.

PS1. I have suspended layout in generation time.

PS2. I have same problem with binding TextBox'es, PictureBoxe's, CheckBox is only example.

How to do that or more littley how to debug the problem, the vs2010 profiler says only the problem is the Binding and i know that.

1. System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(class System.Windows.Forms.Control)
2. System.Windows.Forms.ControlBindingsCollection.Add(class System.Windows.Forms.Binding)

EDIT: *DataContext is from database. (Entity Framework)*

Comment: What is `__bindingsource` looking at?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: __bindingsource is a System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource, he have declarated in other form and binded to the DataGridView in this form, and to this form (dynamicaly) is passed in constructor argument.

Comment: Entity Framework queries are lazy, which in your case means they are executed only at binding time (unless you've forcibly run them before) (by the way, they may even be executed twice at binding time). So if the query is complex, you'll logically see a performance issue at the line you mention. Then, could you show us the construction logics of your query, with indications concerning volumetry?

Comment: @Marcanpilami: I try this and i give you feedback, but however you have any way to unlazy Entity Framework?;-)

Comment: @Svisstack: to force an execution, just use the Execute() function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738469.aspx) and bind to the function result. You can also use whatever function that results in an evaluation of IEnumerables, such as ToList (but in that case it won't be possible to create a two-way binding).

Comment: @Marcanpilami: This is interesting, i try this and give you feedback of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This working not fast because `__bindingsource` have many elements. `Binding` not working good with big collections and this is a problem.

`__bindingsource` is a `BindingSource` class. And must have much less elements to fast working. I solved this problem with creating another new `BindingSource` instance for each *BindingSet* (I mean Binding onetime much elements to properties of one object) with only one element, only this what i want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the problem in your case, but binding can appear to take a long time if it triggers an "event storm". That is you bind to control A, which triggers a change in control B, which triggers a change in control A ....

One thing to check is then the events on the controls you are updating.

The other thing is, from your comments, it looks like you are sharing the __bindingsource between forms. This could be the root of the problem. Why are you doing this? Using a binding source per form would make your program more managable.

Comment: I use same bindingsource, because i want iterate over elements in the table by the binding navigator but if this a root of the problem i can forget this option. I analyze your post tomorow and give you result feedback.

Comment: Binding Context is from Entity Framework, this may be valuable for this problem? Including this: Data to DridGridView from this DataContext is load immediate.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too. I set the `DataSourceUpdateMode` to `Never` (in the `Binding`-class Constructor): The performance was then much much better. If you do not need to update your data source, this is the right way to go.

This performance issue happens due to the Validation-event that is fired. Even if a control loses the focus or is clicked, this fires a validation event, which can decrease drastically the performance of your application.

EDIT: Although I didn't bind to the EntityFramework, the performance was very bad. Setting the `DataSourceUpdateMode` to `Never` reduces the number of events fired. Once you set the `DataSourceUpdatedMode` to `Never`, the updates will be uni-directional: From DataSource to Control.

Comment: I must have DataBinding OneTime from DataSource to Control and always to DataSource From Control with validating data, because in other i take sql error.